# How to read an XML file from a zip file?

Tags: java, xml, zip, inputstream

Is is possible read XML with InputStreamReader in Java?

I have an XML file in a zip file, but I couldn't read that file. how can I do it?

My code:

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

public class testDenemeZipEXtract {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("/home/user/Documents/file.zip");
            Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();

            while(entries.hasMoreElements()){
              ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
              InputStream stream = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);

              if(String.valueOf(entry.getName()).contains(".xml")) {
                BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                while(bf.readLine()!=null){
                  System.out.println(bf.readLine());
                }
              }
            }   
        }catch(Exception e) {}
    }
    
}
```

With running this java class, i am getting this response;

[response image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnADv.png)

This code not print xml as raw text. How can i do it ?

Comment: The code as shown will not compile. Please provide a [mre], and be specific as to the problem you're having.

Comment: Ok, but exactly what is the problem you have with this code? Does it produce an exception? Do you get the wrong output? Does your program freeze? The things that jump out at me is that you request the input stream before you decide whether you want to process the file, and that you never close the reader and input stream. Both could be problematic.

Comment: hi mark, i am updated my question, can you check again ?

Comment: Why my question getting -3 vote, what is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want raw output, you could convert the XML to a string from the ZipInputStream.

```
new String(zipInputStream.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

This will return a string. However, it will not process correctly in a SAX Document builder. It's malformed output.

```
    // org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
    String zipSource = "/{user.home}/path/to/file.zip";
    try {
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(new File(zipSource));
        Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> zipEntries = zipFile.entries();
        while (zipEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
            ZipEntry zipEntry = zipEntries.nextElement();
            String filename = FileUtils.filename(zipEntry.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT));
            if(filename.contains("xccdf") && filename.endsWith("xml")) {
                System.out.println(zipEntry.getName());
                String text = new String(zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry).readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                System.out.println(text);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```